# Can't save/create customer in backend - infinite loading

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, backend

I can't create or save a user, there is just a spinning loading icon in the middle all the time even for half an hour. If I reload the page then I see that nothing has changed.

[image]

What might be the cause?

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: @kunj, no, not a single error in the console.

Comment: Ohh strange, did you checked Magento and server logs?